# Make something live in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have in my Document Ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {       
    showAll();
    var av= $('#a').attr('value');
alert(av);                              <-----**Debugging Value**
    if(av == 1) { 
         alert("1")  
     } else {
         alert("0")
     }
 });
```

The function showAll() calls a PHP and directly generates hidden inputs.

```
<input type='hidden' value='///automatically generated 1 or 0///'>
```

My probelm right now is when I alert av at the **Debugging Value**, it is undefined. And I know this is because that section is not live. How can I make that section live automatically.
If i used live('click', etc etc....) then that works, but I am trying to make it load based on the conditional.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:///

My showProf looks like this:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()         {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("id_verified").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }

xmlhttp.open("GET","showProf.php?i="+myi+"&t=" + Math.random(),true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a callback from your ajax call like

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
```

From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I just editted my script to show what my ajax call looks like, and it looks very different X_X

Comment: If you are using jquery, it's easier to do the ajax call the way @jack suggests

Answer (score 1):

If showAll is making an asynchronous ajax call (which I'm assuming since you said it's a PHP call), then the ajax call has probably not completed yet.  For asynchronous ajax calls, you have to hook the completion callback and do any work after the ajax call from the completion callback function.

Calling an ajax call just starts the call and then your javascript execution continues while the ajax call operates.  That means your debugging statement is happening right after the ajax call has started, not after it's completed.

Comment: Put your code that checks the value of av in the onreadystatechange function when you see that the ajax call is done.  That's the only place you know that the ajax call is actually complete.  If you want, you can place the av code in it's own function and call that function from the onreadystatechange handler when you see completion.  You cannot do it the way you are in document.ready.

Comment: How would I complete the callback? And like isn't it something to do with not selecting the right current like DOM or something?

Comment: I also have a function with a .live('click' etc.... which alerts  $('#a').attr('value'); and that one shows the right value and is not undefined

Comment: Yeah, but you probably only click the link AFTER the ajax call is finished. The problem is that your script procedess BEFORE the ajax call is done. Am I right